# Is there a feature to save questions for personal reference rather than requiring an answer?

Tags: discussion, export

Lately I have begun to compose questions, only to figure out an approach for solving them halfway through. 
Oftentimes I have included references and formatting which adds value to that which I have written as a reference for my own understanding.

I am reluctant to post such questions and then answer them myself as I consider my own personal level of mathematics not to be very advanced, and thus I question the value of some of such entries to the broader stack exchange community.

**Is there a way to save questions as notes rather than questions requiring an answer (I.e notepad feature)?**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post on Meta, not here. But isn't this something you could do using a TeX processor on your own machine?

Comment: Why not just write them up on your computer using LaTeX?

Comment: I mean, you could use notepad? Or your favorite text editor. If you're in the habit of writing TeX, you could of course save the TeX. Or you could email these things to yourself. Or make a blog? Actually, I'm not sure what you want from MathSE. Are you asking for a place where you can do something like keep a journal of math notes for yourself? This sounds like something a private blog (even a free blog) would do well.

Comment: thanks for the comments about a TeX editor for my own machine. I hadn't considered this possibility.

Comment: You may also want to look at [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com).

Comment: There's also [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), which supports both Markdown and MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly many solutions how to do this off-site. (Some were suggested in the comments.)

I will also point out that you could post a question and immediately delete it. You still can see it if you *keep the link*.

Some things to keep in mind:

- Many deleted questions can lead to [question ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info).
- You can no longer edit the question while it is deleted. (But you can edit an answer, if you post one too.)
- If you favorite the question so that you can find it more easily, other [10k+ users](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see the question if they look at [your favorites](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites). (And also if the question appears on some other list of questions, 10k+ users can still see it. However, from the top of my head I cannot think of another list where the question is likely to appear.
- 10k+ users can view deleted question *if they have link to it*. So theoretically it might still be visible to some other users. (If they notice the question during the short period while it is not deleted or if they have the link from somewhere.)

Related question: [Would using deleted (“hidden”) questions on math.SE for personal use be considered misuse of the site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23285)

Still, I think using some tool to store the question elsewhere is *better*. The only advantage of this approach that I can see that you have question (possibly with some answers) available directly here on the site. (This is definitely *not ideal,* but it is the ony possibility how to do this *within the site* if you want the post to be accessible mainly to you.)